# Incompatiblity with the layer in the image captioning model

Tags: python, image, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

i am working on a image captioning model using flikr8k dataset. when i try to fit the model i am getting this error.

```
***ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 2048 but received input with shape (None, 1)***
```

This is https://www.kaggle.com/shadabhussain/automated-image-captioning-flickr8/comments code i am trying to replicate.

but the moment i ran model.fit i get a value error.

```
conca = Concatenate()([image_model.output, language_model.output])
x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(conca)
x = LSTM(512, return_sequences=False)(x)
x = Dense(vocab_size)(x)
out = Activation('softmax')(x)
model = Model(inputs=[image_model.input, language_model.input], outputs = out)

# model.load_weights("../input/model_weights.h5")
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
hist = model.fit([images, captions], next_words, batch_size=512, epochs=200)
```

[I have attached the image of the model architecture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wy32c.png)

Thanks

Comment: The dense( image model first) layer is expecting (None, 2048) shape but it is getting (None, 1) could you please check the input parameters for model.fit() function, especially images such that it's shape is (Something, 2048).

Comment: For input the Image size is (224,224,3) and model fir code is model.fit([images, captions], next_words, batch_size=512, epochs=200)